# Scaling step in Baum-Welch algorithm

Tags: hidden-markov-model, optimal-scaling, baum-welch

I am implementing the Baum-Welch Algorithm for training a Hidden Markov Process, to basically better understand the training process.

I have implemented the iterative procedures described in Rabiner's classic [paper](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf). My Implementation is in `Wolfram Mathematica`. The problem I am facing is the scaling step, if the sequence is 100 observations long then the probabilities easily cross the bounds of $10^{-30}$.

My question is can anyone explain or provide a link where the calculation of scaled forward and backward matrices is described?

For the forward procedure the code is as follows:

```
 ForwardProcedure[TM_, EM_, P_, N_, M_, Seq_] := 
 Module[{DP, i, j, DPPart},
  DP = ConstantArray[0, {N, M}];
  DP[[1, All]] = Table[P[[i]]*EM[[i, Part[Seq, 1]]], {i, 1, N}];
  DP = Table[
    If[j == 1, P[[i]]*EM[[i, Part[Seq, 1]]], 0]
    , {i, 1, N}, {j, 1, Length@Seq}];
  For[j = 2, j <= Length@Seq, j++,
   DPPart = DP[[All, j - 1]];
   For[i = 1, i <= N, i++,
    DP[[i, j]] = Dot[DPPart, TM[[All, i]]]*EM[[i, Part[Seq, j]]];
    ];
   ];
  DP
  ]
```

Essentially `DP[[i, j]] = Dot[DPPart, TM[[All, i]]]*EM[[i, Part[Seq, j]]];` This line is the update. Which simply takes the needed columns from Transition (TM), The alpha (DP) matrices and multiplies with the associated Emission value.

How can I have a scaling factor independent of i, when not all the t-s of the row of the DP matrix are filled?

Comment: Asking us to debug your code is off topic here. Fwiw though If I remember correctly HMMs have the alpha and beta sequences of distributions, but you don't always want to use them exactly like that because joint probabilities are always too small for any non trivial time series

Comment: I'm not asking to debug it. I just put it here for reference, if anyone ever wanted to see how it is actually implemented. This code works correctly, However does not scale the parameters. You are right there are alpha and beta sequences this code calculates alpha, and the reason you gave is precisely why we need scaling I was asking if someone can actually explain the scaling procedure, because I'm stuck at some point in Rabiner's paper.

Comment: okey dokey close vote retracted. I've worked through this same problem before so I'll check back in later when I'm in front of my computer (cell phone now).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Background and Notation

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_T$ be the observations, and $z_1, \ldots, z_T$ be the hidden states. The forward-backward recursions are written in terms of $\alpha(z_n)$ and $\beta(z_n)$.

$\alpha(z_n) = p(x_1,\ldots,x_n,z_n)$ is the joint distribution of all the heretofore observed data and the most recent state. As $n$ gets large, this gets very small. This is just because of simple properties of probabilities. Probabilities of subsets get smaller. This is axiomatic.

$\beta(z_n) = p(x_{n+1},\ldots,x_T|z_n)$ is the probability of all the future data given the current state. This gets small as $n$ goes down, for the same reasons as above.

### Forward Algorithm

You can see that both of these things become very small, and hence cause numerical issues, whenever you have a non-tiny dataset. So instead of using the forward recursion
$$
\alpha(z_n) = p(x_n|z_n) \sum_{z_{n-1}}\alpha(z_{n-1})p(z_n|z_{n-1})
$$
use the **filtering recursion**:
$$
p(z_n|x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{p(x_n|z_n)\sum_{z_{n-1}} p(z_n|z_{n-1})p(z_{n-1}|x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})}{p(x_n|x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})}.
$$
You can get this algebraically by dividing both sides of the first recursion by $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. But I would program it by keeping track of the filtering distributions, not the $\alpha$ quantities. You also don't need to worry about the normalizing constant usually--the last step you can normalize your probability vector if your state space isn't too large.

I am more familiar with the non-HMM state space model literature, and the filtering recursions are probably the most common set of recursions. I have found a few results on the internet where HMM people call this procedure "scaling." So it's nice to find this connection and figure out what all this $\alpha$ stuff is.

### Backward Algorithm

Next, the traditional HMM backward algorithm is stated as
$$
\beta(z_n) = \sum_{z_{n+1}}\beta(z_{n+1})p(x_{n+1}|z_{n+1})p(z_{n+1}|z_n).
$$
This one is trickier though. I have found a few websites that say to divide both sides by $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ again, and I have also found resources that say to divide both sides by $p(x_{t+1},\ldots,x_T|x_1,\ldots,x_t)$. I'm still working this out, though. Also, I suspect there's another connection between this and the backward recursions in other areas of state space model literature (for marginal and joint smoothing distributions). I'll keep you posted.

### Edit:

It turns out if you multiply both sides of the HMM backward equation above by $p(x_1, \ldots, x_n,z_n)/p(x_1,\ldots,x_T)$ you get the backward equation for the marginal smoothing distribution, which are more common in non-HMM state space models.

$$
p(z_n|x_1,\ldots,x_T) = p(z_n|x_1,\ldots,x_n) \sum_{z_{n+1}}\frac{p(z_{n+1}|z_n)}{p(z_{n+1}|x_1,\ldots,x_n)}p(z_{n+1}|x_1,\ldots,x_T).
$$

I don't know if this is standard for using Baum-Welch, but it's pretty standard with other state space models. Cool.

### Edit 2:

https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387402642 define on page 63 the normalized backward function as

$$
\hat{\beta}(z_n) = \beta(z_n)\frac{p(x_{1:n})}{p(x_{1:T})} = \frac{p(z_n \mid x_{1:T}) }{p(z_n \mid x_{1:n})},
$$
which, as they mention on page 65, has the interpretation of the ratio of two marginal smoothing distributions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in HMM, but happened to go through the same process of learning and implementing HMM while encountering the same normalization issues. Below is the answer based on my understanding.

### - Forward algorithm:

The forward algorithm calculates $\alpha_t(j) \equiv P(z_t = j | x_{1:t})$, i.e., the probability that the hidden state $z_t$ at time $t$ is $j$, given the observed data points up to time $t$. 
In vector form:

$\alpha_1 \propto \phi_t \odot \pi$

$\alpha_t \propto \phi_t \odot (A^T \alpha_{t-1})$, for $t=2,\dots,T$

Where $\phi_t(j) \equiv P(x_t | z_t = j)$ is the local evidence, $\pi$ the prior distribution over states, and $A$ the transition matrix whose entry $A[i, j]$ corresponds to the transition probability from state i to state j, i.e., $A[i, j] = P(z_{t+1} = j | z_{t} = i)$.

Since the above $\alpha_t$'s are not normalized, let's write a (Python) procedure to normalize a vector:

```
def normalize(v):
    norm = np.sum(v)
    v = v/norm
    return (v, norm)
```

With the normalization procedure defined above, we can normalize the $\alpha_t$'s:

$\hat{\alpha}_t, \text{norm}_t$ = normalize($\alpha$), for $t=1,\dots,T$

### - Backward algorithm:

The backward algorithm calculates $\beta_t(j) \equiv P(x_{t+1:T} | z_t = j)$, i.e., the likelihood of future evidence given that the hidden state $z_t$ at time $t$ is $j$.

In vector form:

$\beta_T = 1_{\mathbf{K}}$

$\beta_{t} = A (\phi_{t+1} \odot \beta_{t+1})$, for $t = T-1, \dots, 1$

Where $K$ is the number of hidden states.

Note that $\beta_t(j)$ is *not* a probability distribution over states, hence $\sum_j \beta_t(j) \neq 1$.

The catch here is that we can normalize $\beta_t$ with the normalization factor we previously use to normalize $\alpha_t$, $\text{norm}_t$ calculated above.

$\hat{\beta}_t = \beta_t / \text{norm}_t$, for $t=1,\dots,T$

The rationale is described in the next bullet.

### - Forward-Backward:

In this step, we calculate $\gamma_t(j) \equiv P(z_t=j | x_{1:T})$, i.e., the smoothed marginal given the fully observed sequence of data points.

One can show that $\gamma_t(j) \propto \alpha_t(j) \beta_t(j)$. In vector form:

$\gamma_t \propto \alpha_t \odot \beta_t \propto \hat{\alpha}_t \odot \hat{\beta}_t$, for $t=1,\dots,T$

Since $\hat{\alpha}_t$ carries the normalization factors: $\text{norm}_1, \text{norm}_2, \dots, \text{norm}_t$,

and $\hat{\beta}_t$ carries the normalization factors $\text{norm}_T, \text{norm}_{T-1}, \dots, \text{norm}_{t+1}$,

therefore **for all the $\gamma_t$'s, they all have the same factor**: $\prod_{t=1}^T \text{norm}_t$.